# Using template parameters as modifiers to xml pointers (xpaths)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

I have searched all morning and yesterday afternoon and still cannot find an solution to my problem. It would be wonderful if you would help.

I am working on an xsl-fo file that will be translated to PDF format with apache fop. I am trying to use parameters to modify xpaths to my xml file. It is a much more complicated system than the example following, but I have simplified it to the root of the problem.

Suppose my xml file looks like:

```
<sc931>
    <whyoming>
              <train>
                   <miles>98</miles>
                   <time>9888</time>
    </whyoming>
    <georgia>
              <train>
                   <miles>98</miles>
                   <time>9888</time>
    </georgia>
</sc931>
```

What I am trying to do is use a template parameter to access these values like so:

Declaration of parameter

```
<xsl:param name="state" select="whyoming"/>
```

Call

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(/sc931/, $state, /train/miles)"/>
```

But this call does not work because the concat function returns a string rather than a pointer to the proper node. What is the correct way to use a template parameter to modify an address given to a value-of statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before XSLT 3.0 there is no dynamic XPath evaluation but for your simple case it should suffice to use `<xsl:value-of select="/sc931/*[local-name() = $state]/train/miles"/>`.

[edit]I overlooked that your param is defined as `<xsl:param name="state" select="whyoming"/>`, you need to change that to `<xsl:param name="state" select="'whyoming'"/>` for my suggestion to work.

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you Martin!!